# Too many MySQL connections on WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, wampserver

I install word-press on my Ubuntu server. I only have 3 blog post but it reach max_connection within hour.So whenever my user kit my blog it's show database establish error. my log file have following entry

`server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
[Mon Jun 20 06:30:21.877663 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 43436] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down`

my default max_connection is 200 now i increase it to 1024.

Comment: Look at your Apache error and access logs to clarify if there was anything else suspicious and how many people actually consulted the site in the previous minutes.  It would be a good idea to specify what your actual `max_connection`.

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information to get the help you want. This is almost nothing and therefore it is hardly sufficient information to solve your problem

Comment: once i increase max_connection to 1024 it's work fine. but i think that it's not the real issue. anyone help

Comment: for three blog it make 564 connections

Comment: Check you wait_timeout variable. Default value is 8 hours = 28800 seconds.

Comment: i reduce it to 1000. it's correct or not

Comment: It is not correct. Keep it as it was, and check your application. Also run SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; on database to check how many connections running.